# webpack watcher doesn't update on v1.13.0

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

**edit**: seems to be a webpack related bug on v1.13.0, if anyone encounters it, answer is below

---

I'm running `webpack -w` but for some reason it only re-runs occasionally after doing lots of changes, but not file-save like usual. For example, changing a class name in one of my react components's HTML on it's render method does nothing to trigger the webpack watcher. Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './main.js',
    output: {
        path: './public/build/',
        filename: 'index.js'
    },
    /*devServer: {
        // reload on the fly
        inline: true,
        port: 3333
    },*/
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

I also tried to run the webpack dev server using `webpack-dev-server` from the command line (uncommenting the devServer part from my config file), but that one doesn't update on file changes at all.

I've been trying to work like this but it's tiresome having to restart even `webpack -w` just to see a minor change

Comment: You might want to report this regression so it can get fixed.

Comment: Ah, I see you did that. Thanks. :+1:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it...for some reason, adding the following to `webpack.config.js` solved it. No idea why, but this fixes it. Might be I'm on Windows 7, also webpack v1.13.0

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
```

and this as part of the module.exports

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.OldWatchingPlugin()
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
webpack --watch
```

As they recommend on they webpage: https://webpack.github.io/docs/cli.html#watch-mode-watch.

I normally run webpack like this:

```
webpack --config webpack.config.js --progress --colors --watch
```

To see all the meaningful log